# iOS background music problems

Tags: ios, xcode, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS SDK : playing music on the background and switching views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467533/ios-sdk-playing-music-on-the-background-and-switching-views)

Hi guys im currently using this code to play background music in my app when its launched .But when i switch views to my SecondView and return back to my Firstview the music starts over and overlaps the music that is currently playing and it keeps overlapping music when i return back to my Firstview, how can i have the music start over when i switch back to my Firstview from my SecondView.

FirstViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drums" ofType:@"mp3"];
  theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPathath] error:NULL];
  theAudio.delegate = self;
  theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
  [theAudio play];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use NSUserDefaults to save the music playing status, so when the view is loaded, the music will only be played if it hasn't already.

```
 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"music"] == nil) {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drums" ofType:@"mp3"];
    theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPathath] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [theAudio play]; 
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"-" forKey:@"music"]; }
```

You need to reset this key back to nil when quitting the app. Otherwise, if the player quit the app, and next time when the app is restarted the @"music" string wouldn't be nil.

Go to the **projectAppDelegate.m** file:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"music"]; }
```

If the music is being played throughout the app, then put the music playing codes as shown below to be safe. Don't forget to declare the AVAudioPlayer *theAudio in projectAppDelegate.h file.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drums" ofType:@"mp3"];
    theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPathath] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [theAudio play]; 
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"-" forKey:@"music"]; }
```

I might have missed a few bits here. Just run a few tests to make it the way you like to work. I just tried on my app and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Two option,

1- stop the player while first view is disappear.

```
[theAudio stop]  in `viewWillDisappear`
```

2- if you don't want to play again on come back.
declare `theAudio` in appDelegate class. and before allocating check whether it is allocated or not.

```
if(!appDelegate.theAudio)
{
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drums" ofType:@"mp3"];
  appDelegate.theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPathath]   error:NULL];
  theAudio.delegate = self;
  theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
  [theAudio play]; 
}
else
{

 [theAudiostop];
   [theAudio play];
}
```

Comment: well i need the background music to play across all views and need the music to restart when i hit my home button back to my firstview.Currently i added [theAudio prepareToPlay]; to   -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{  .. and when i hit the home button back to my FirstView the music continues to play , it works fine but i would like the background music to restart when i hit my home button back to my FirstView.

Answer (score 0):

You are reallocating and recreating the AVAudioPlayer each time you display the view. You should avoid this if possible. As a solution to your problem, depending on your code,  call `[theAudio stop]` in `viewDidDisappear` or `viewDidUnload` events. This will stop your audio player when its view enters background.

Comment: Yeah you can call [theAudio stop] in viewDidDisappear or viewWillDisappear. But not in viewDidUnload as it is only called when any memory warning is raised, not otherwise...

Comment: well i need the background music to play across all views and need the music to restart when i hit my home button back to my firstview. i tried the [theAudio stop] under ViewDidDisappear but it stops the music when switching across the views and i dont need that option .