# iOS SDK :AVAudioPlayer playing music on the background and switching views keeps overlapping

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS SDK : playing music on the background and switching views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467533/ios-sdk-playing-music-on-the-background-and-switching-views)

I am trying to play music in my application. The music works fine but after switching viewControllers and returning to the main menu, the music plays again! It means several identical sounds play together! How can I solve this.?

firtview.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
}
@end
```

firstview.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GENIEAPP" ofType:@"mp3"];
theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;




[super viewDidLoad];
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have a few problems here, first of when the view loads you are playing the sound, now i dont know if you are trying to deallocte that views viewController, but when you do, you probably dont release and stop the sound, so you are leaking the AVAudioPlayer, since you dont release and stop playing the audio Player, you reallocate the player when you come back to the view controller and it starts playing again... Not sure what your intentions are, but if they are to play the sound only when the view controller is allocated, then you should in the dealloc method or wherever appripriate, stop the avaudioplayer and deallocate it... if you are trying to play your sound throught the app then you need to maybe allocate the player elsewhere... 
Looking at your comment, somthing like this might do the trick for you

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GENIEAPP" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if(!theAudio){
        theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

        theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
        [theAudio play];
    }
    else
    {
        //stop the sound and play it again
        [theAudio stop];
        [theAudio play];
    }
}
```

Comment: well i would like the sounds to play across my 3 views and when i hit the home button back to my first view i would like the music to restart. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? If this is how I should do it, where do I start?

Comment: when viewDidLoad fires the second time is your audio player already allocated?

Comment: yah when ViewDidLoad first starts its allocated

Comment: Hmmmm ..hey Daniel i tried the edit and now the music wont play when the app starts

Comment: Right u need to put a start in the first if

Comment: ok with the edit i still get music overlapping when i switch from my secondview back to my firstview.on my secondview when i hit the home button back to the firstview a new track overlaps the current track playing. =(

Comment: understand what the code does and fix it, you basically cant have the player playing more than once..

Comment: i understand that AVAudioPlayer is called everytime i go back to my firstview so thats why im getting ovelapping music  , but i dont understand how to restart it i been to xcode docs but i havent seen code to restart AVAudioPlayer i found playattime and preparetoplay but they dont fix the problem. i hit a wall because im not sure how to dealloc AVAudioPlayer properly..